# Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted required capabilities on Selenium grid while running Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, session

Am new for selenium grid while launching the driver against the    selenium grid port produced unreachable error:

```
ionixx@thangaraj:/$ **appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 33431 -bp 2254 --udid    4100fd5a18d17000 --session-override**  [Appium] Welcome to Appium    v1.5.3 (REV 55db1892873be30aebbb9afe1adcd36a94d1a450)
[Appium]    Non-default server args: [Appium]   address: '127.0.0.1'
[Appium]      port: 33431 [Appium]   bootstrapPort: 2254 [Appium]     
sessionOverride: true [Appium]   udid: '4100fd5a18d17000' [Appium]   
Deprecated server args: [Appium]   -U,--udid =>   
--default-capabilities '{"udid":"4100fd5a18d17000"}' [Appium] Default capabilities, which will be added to each request unless overridden   
by desired capabilities: [Appium]   udid: '4100fd5a18d17000' [Appium] 
Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:**33431**   
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session   
{"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/ionixx/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/xxxxxxxxxxxx.apk","appPackage":"
cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","appActivity":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","noReset":"true","newCommandTimeout":500000,"BROWSER_NAME":"","VERSION":"4.4.2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Nexas"},"requiredCapabilities":null},"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/ionixx/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/xxxxxxxx.apk","appPackage":"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","appActivity":"xxxxxxxxxx","noReset":"true","newCommandTimeout":500000,"BROWSER_NAME":"","VERSION":"4.4.2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Nexas"},"requiredCapabilities":null}
[debug] [MJSONWP] **Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters   
were incorrect. We wanted   
{"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","sessionId","id"]}
and you sent   
["capabilities","desiredCapabilities","requiredCapabilities"]**   
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 7 ms - 201  [HTTP] --> POST   
/wd/hub/session   
{"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/ionixx/Android/Sdk/platform-toolsxxxxxxxxxxxx.apk","appPackage":"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","appActivity":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","noReset":"true","newCommandTimeout":500000,"BROWSER_NAME":"","VERSION":"4.4.2","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Nexas"},"requiredCapabilities":null}}
```

Comment: I got this error : Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities … required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: Issue is due to invalid apk file path, after changing valid path worked for me.

Comment: I try to update app path  but no result ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812593/unable-to-create-new-remote-session-desired-capabilities-capabilities/41827503?noredirect=1#comment70843587_41827503

Comment: Check whether the appium port is in up.

Comment: yes it is right !

Comment: It's a build permission issue do one thing. try to execute this command. Its should launch your app in your device.  xxxxx@thangaraj:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb -s <<device_name>> shell "am start -S -a  android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n  <<app.package>>/<<app.activity>>"

Comment: still face the issue ! any suggestion ?

Comment: @Emna Have you tried above mentioned adb command.

Comment: i dont know what to use after typing :  adb -s SM-G360H shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.bulldozer.gaa/com.bulldozer.gaa.activities.MainActivity 
i got >

Comment: always same error :'(

Comment: The error in appium log which you attached in your issue is "Original error: Permission to start activity denied." It's looks like a build permission issue, ask your developer team to add following line in the main activity of the manifest file "android:exported="true" and then try again.

Comment: ok i'll try with this way thanks !

Comment: it's being better now i just tried with another application it's working ok ! 
But now i'm facing a new issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976782/application-crash-at-the-moment-i-run-my-testng-while-using-appium

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by changing the application, it seems the problem came from an old an apk file I was using!