# Unable to create new remote session while testing an Android application with Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to run an Example of test scripts coded with java in Eclipse with Appium. I run Appium by npm (i'm using Appium 1.6.3, i'm not new to Appium i run it before on Mac and on windows without any problem but this time in Ubuntu it looks a bit different while it's not with the appium application but with console)

```
appium --address 127.0.0.1
```

I'm using

- java-client-4.1.2.jar
- selenium-java-3.0.1.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
- testng-6.9.10.jar

And my java class is :

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class FirstTest {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    File path = new File("/home/emna/Téléchargements/AutomationFiles/app-release.apk");


    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        System.out.println("app Dir.--->" + path);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "SM-G360H");
        capabilities.setCapability("version", "4.4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "platform");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "***************");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", path.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.bulldozer.gaa");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
                "com.bulldozer.gaa.activities.MainActivity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() throws InterruptedException {

        // driver.wait(10000);
        System.out.println("GAA");
        driver.findElement(By.id("acceptCheckbox")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("continueBtn")).click();

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

But the problem is that :

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /tmp/testng-eclipse--2049046107/testng-customsuite.xml

app Dir.--->/home/emna/Téléchargements/AutomationFiles/app-release.apk
Jan 24, 2017 1:14:44 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 24, 2017 1:14:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Jan 24, 2017 1:15:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=/home/emna/Téléchargements/AutomationFiles/app-release.apk, appPackage=com.bulldozer.gaa, appActivity=com.bulldozer.gaa.activities.MainActivity, platformVersion=platform, platformName=Android, udid=*************, deviceName=SM-G360H, version=4.4.4}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'tarek-Vostro-3902', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-59-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
```

Here the Appium log file :

```
    [debug] [ADB] Running '/home/emna/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","***************","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[debug] [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Permission to start activity denied.
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (../../../lib/tools/apk-utils.js:80:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 11015 ms - 223 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/home/emna/Téléchargements/AutomationFiles/app-release.apk","appPackage":"com.bulldozer.gaa","appActivity":"com.bulldozer.gaa.activities.MainActivity","platformVersion":"platform","platformName":"Android","udid":"************","deviceName":"SM-G360H","version":"4.4.4"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Bad parameters: BadParametersError: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["desiredCapabilities"],"optional":["requiredCapabilities","capabilities","sessionId","id","sessionId","id","sessionId","id"]} and you sent ["capabilities"]
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 400 5 ms - 205
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the apk file itself, I used an other .`apk file` with the same configuration i have used and it works fine !

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the most important capability, which is the path to the .apk:

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "appPath");
```

Also, i would recommend on changing from RemoteWebDriver to Android driver, since you will have some more functionality:

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(....)
```

ps: you can update your java-client to 4.1.2 and testng to 6.9.10

Comment: Thanks @David, i'll try. But app path isn't required while i'm with real device and app is installed there. Isn't ?

Comment: appPath is required at all times!

Comment: Still have the same error : FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=/home/emna/Téléchargements/AutomationFiles/app-release.apk, appPackage=com.bulldozer.gaa, appActivity=com.bulldozer.gaa.activities.MainActivity, platformVersion=platform, platformName=Android, udid=*********, deviceName=SM-G360H, version=4.4.4}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'

Comment: can you start appium without --address and try again?

Comment: ok i have just updated my question after using what you have proposed at the first

Comment: still have the same problem !

Comment: Your Emulator is running, right? 
can you type "adb devices" and check if the avd's status is "online"?

Comment: it's on real device, it gets unlocked ; it's connected !

Comment: Emma, lets make it as generic as possible
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                    capabilities.setCapability("app", appPath);
                    capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
                    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
                    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");                        
                    capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 40);
                    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Comment: i also try to uninstall the application from the phone but it was the same error !

Comment: These basic capabilities should just run on any open device, avd or real device

Comment: Emma, just to make sure.
Developer options + debugging is switched on in the android phone. right?

Comment: No, please just try to run the test with these very basic capabilities.
Also, what is the appium server version that you are using?

Comment: i'm using appium 1.6.3 (installed by npm)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133891/discussion-between-emna-and-david-ep).

Comment: It's a build permission issue do one thing. try to execute this command. Its should launch your app in your device. xxxxx@thangaraj:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb -s <<device_name>> shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n <<app.package>>/<<app.activity>>"

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your Appium is running already the app using GUI settings.

Simultaneously you are trying to run it again from your code.

What should help : In Appium UI go to Android settings (basic)

1. Application panel: do not define / launch the app and its activities.
2. Capabilities panel: define and select {Platform Name, Automation Name, Platform Version}

Comment: I'm not using appium app, i only run appium with npm, shall i update anything in the command `appium --address 127.0.0.1` i have tapped in console  ? i'm using ubuntu

Comment: Try to kill all appium processes first. Run the emulator on your own.
This is how Appium works in my case, related to my post
`Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' appium/build/lib/main.js --debug-log-spacing --automation-name "Appium" --platform-name "Android" --platform-version "6.0" --device-name "emulator-5554"`
Then, the emulator "emulator-5554" should be detected

Comment: i'm using real device not emulator

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue, since as I understood you are running Appium on the same machine where your client scripts reside, try using "http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub" instead. this Solution works for me

```
 AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```